# Multiple if and or conditions

Tags: javascript

I am currently trying to make a filter functionality in JavaScript allowing you to select from a pre-defined list to narrow down the selected options.

The filter has multiple options, it's simple enough to narrow down the list based on matches in the filter, one option at the time. But I want to narrow down the list based on matches if multiple options are selected.

Example: User enters "Hello" as a filter option for the key "Company", this would result in selections only matching Company == Hello. If a user then selects a second option, "Good day" for the key "Position", then I only want to narrow down the list if the key "Company" AND "Position" matches.

Without actually writing any code yet, then i know that this can be done with a lot of AND OR's, but i'm hoping that there is a much more convenient way to do this that i'm not seeing.

```
var position    = $('select[name=order_position]').select2('val');
var industry    = $('select[name=order_industry]').select2('val');
var company     = $('select[name=order_company]').select2('val');

$('.mail_select_prospect').each(function() {

    var prospect_existing = $(this).attr('data-existing');
    var prospect_position = $(this).attr('data-position');
    var prospect_industry = $(this).attr('data-industry');
    var prospect_company = $(this).attr('data-company');
    var self = $(this);

    if(
        ( $.inArray( prospect_position, position ) !== -1 ) ||
        ( $.inArray( prospect_industry, industry ) !== -1 ) ||
        ( $.inArray( prospect_company, company ) !== -1 ) ||
        ( $( 'input[name=order_existing]' ).is( ':checked' ) && prospect_existing == 1 ) ||
        ( $( 'input[name=order_nonexisting]' ).is( ':checked' ) && prospect_existing == 2 )
    ) {

        self.prop('checked', true);

    } else {

        self.prop('checked', false);

    }

});
```

This is what i currently have, this finds matches based on one key matching, while I only want results that match ALL filter selections. Not just the one.

Using && the entire way will force the user to choose something on every filter option before the filter kicks in (Obviously), I want it to be possible to select one keyword and get matches with those who have that keyword or if two keywords are selected I only want matches where both keywords are present.

Any advice?

Comment: Of course it's possible but we need to know in what context inorder to help you out. If you are generating a list of things based on input values then you could generate each part only if that one value is selected, and therefor the more that they select, the more is generated. Could you post more code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might suggest using the [conditional ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). If a filter criterion is defined, you use it; otherwise the check for that criterion should always pass. So, a stripped down example might be something like

```
if (
    ( position && position.length ? $.inArray( prospect_position, position ) !== -1 : true )
    && ( industry && industry.length ? $.inArray( prospect_industry, industry ) !== -1 : true )
    && ( $( 'input[name=order_existing]' ).is( ':checked' ) ?prospect_existing == 1 : true)
) {
    ...
}
```

Also, since you're in your current example code just setting a value true or false based on this conditional check, you could just assign the filtering result  directly (or using an interim variable for clarity),

```
var include = ( position && position.length ? $.inArray( prospect_position, position ) !== -1 : true ) &&  ... ;
self.prop('checked', include);
```

Comment: This almost works. But i only get results if prospect_existing is true.

Comment: Well, I at first had a mistake in my example code where I had the .is(':checked') condition and prospect_existing == 1 comparisons reversed. I fixed this right before your comment it seems, perhaps you copied the mistake.

Comment: Awesome! Really awesome. `?prospect_existing == 1 ?` should be `?prospect_existing == 1 :` But besides that it's perfect.